# Check for a file version from a Wix Bootstrapper Bundle

Tags: wix, burn

I've created a bootstrapper application for my WIX installer. One of the installers that I am bundling needs to have an install condition based on the version of a file that is allready installed. I don't have access to the source of the installer in question, so I can't put the condition in that installer.

I have found [in the documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_the_version_number.htm) how to create a file version based condition inside of an MSI. ()

My question is how do I use a similar condition directly in an bootstrapper project.

Answer (score 2):

Use FileSearch from WixUtilExtension to get the version of the file into a Burn variable. You can use the Burn variable in a package's InstallCondition.

Comment: How do I search for a file version that is not necessarily in a fixed path? I have an outlook plugin, and to find out the outlook version i need to go to one registry key to find the outlook current version, and based on that i must go to another registry key specific to that outlook version that tells me where that specific version of outlook is installed. THEN I must find the version of outlook.exe to find out if it is SP3 or not

Answer (score 2):

as stated by Bob Arnson, you can get a version in bootstrap project like this

```
<util:FileSearch  
        Id="CheckVer"
        Path="[CommonFilesFolder]\xyz\xyz\abc.dll"
        Variable="FILEVERSION" 
        Result="version" />
```

FILEVERSION will contain the version of the dll or exe.
as described in the documentation
[FileSearch Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/filesearch.html)